# Parse JSON to objects without any third-party tools

Tags: .net, vb.net, json, parsing, text-mining

How do I parse [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) using VB.NET without any third-party tools?

I know that there is the JSON.NET tool which parses the JSON string to objects and [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML).

What would be a method for parsing it?

Please don't reply saying "Why not use JSON.NET?". I want to create my own methods.

Comment: You might have fun implementing the productions specified at [json.org](http://www.json.org/). In fact I think it is a great syntax to learn parsing with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the commenter said, http://www.json.org/ has all the control flow logic you need to do a simple implementation. Implementing your own **basic** version should not be too hard. I would strongly recommend using a third party one - I have had to hand crank my own one in C back in the day and it was not fun.

PS: An existing parser can save you lots of time and grey hairs when developing your own parser, use something like https://jsonformatter.org/json-parser